# Import csv with json inside in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to import with Pandas a CSV file that looks like the following:

First line:

```
LOAD_ID,CHAIN_ID,BLOCK,TIMESTAMP,TX_HASH,CALL_ID,CALL_TYPE,FROM_ADDRESS,FROM_NAME,TO_ADDRESS,TO_NAME,FUNCTION_SIGNATURE,FUNCTION_NAME,VALUE,ARGUMENTS,RAW_ARGUMENTS,OUTPUTS,RAW_OUTPUTS,GAS_USED,ERROR,STATUS,ORDER_INDEX,DECODING_STATUS,STORAGE_ADDRESS
```

Other lines:

```
2022-05-09 14:57:50.000,mainnet,12023665,2021-03-12 12:27:23.000,0x2c6006b6a82b58574fc9d3b60455d343d976f03ae7dd2dd7dc064139315c2755,0_3,call,0x19a8ed4860007a66805782ed7e0bed4e44fc6717,Marketplace,0xf87e31492faf9a91b02ee0deaad50d51d56d5d4d,LAND,0xe985e9c5,isApprovedForAll,0.00000000,{"operator":"0x8e5660b4ab70168b5a6feea0e0315cb49c8cd539"\,"owner":"0x821d9a3f2ea71e19c862218f4b041fa5a2827490"},[{"name":"owner"\,"raw":"0x000000000000000000000000821d9a3f2ea71e19c862218f4b041fa5a2827490"\,"type":"address"}\,{"name":"operator"\,"raw":"0x0000000000000000000000008e5660b4ab70168b5a6feea0e0315cb49c8cd539"\,"type":"address"}],{"__out0":"True"},[{"name":""\,"raw":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"\,"type":"bool"}],6288,\\N,true,4855,true,0xf87e31492faf9a91b02ee0deaad50d51d56d5d4d
```

I've tried with `df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=",", engine='python')` but it continues to give the error `',' expected after '"'`.

I believe that the part with JSON-like data is causing the error but I don't know how to fix it.

**UPDATE:**

I added `engine=python` to avoid the error: `Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 28 fields in line 5, saw 32`.

The full trace of the error is:

```
File c:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py:760, in PythonParser._next_iter_line(self, row_num)
    759 assert self.data is not None
--> 760 line = next(self.data)
    761 # for mypy

Error: ',' expected after '"'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Utente\Desktop\pm-decentraland\scripts\traces_internal_execution.ipynb Cell 1' in <cell line: 12>()
      3 import pandas as pd
      6 # path = r'C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\sf_csv'
      7 # all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
      8 
      9 # df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f,  sep=',', quotechar='"', error_bad_lines=False)
     10 #                for f in all_files))
---> 12 df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\sf_csv\output_files_0_0_0.csv', sep=",", engine='python')
     14 print(df)

File c:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:311, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    305 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    306     warnings.warn(
    307         msg.format(arguments=arguments),
    308         FutureWarning,
    309         stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310     )
--> 311 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File c:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:680, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    665 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
    666     dialect,
    667     delimiter,
   (...)
    676     defaults={"delimiter": ","},
    677 )
    678 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
--> 680 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File c:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:575, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    572 _validate_names(kwds.get("names", None))
    574 # Create the parser.
--> 575 parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    577 if chunksize or iterator:
    578     return parser

File c:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:933, in TextFileReader.__init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    930     self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    932 self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
--> 933 self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)

File c:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1235, in TextFileReader._make_engine(self, f, engine)
   1232     raise ValueError(msg)
   1234 try:
-> 1235     return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
   1236 except Exception:
   1237     if self.handles is not None:

File c:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py:138, in PythonParser.__init__(self, f, **kwds)
    134 # needs to be cleaned/refactored
    135 # multiple date column thing turning into a real spaghetti factory
    137 if not self._has_complex_date_col:
--> 138     (index_names, self.orig_names, self.columns) = self._get_index_name(
    139         self.columns
    140     )
    141     self._name_processed = True
    142     if self.index_names is None:

File c:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py:899, in PythonParser._get_index_name(self, columns)
    897 else:
    898     try:
--> 899         line = self._next_line()
    900     except StopIteration:
    901         line = None

File c:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py:696, in PythonParser._next_line(self)
    693     next(self.data)
    695 while True:
--> 696     orig_line = self._next_iter_line(row_num=self.pos + 1)
    697     self.pos += 1
    699     if orig_line is not None:

File c:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py:789, in PythonParser._next_iter_line(self, row_num)
    780         reason = (
    781             "Error could possibly be due to "
    782             "parsing errors in the skipped footer rows "
   (...)
    785             "all rows)."
    786         )
    787         msg += ". " + reason
--> 789     self._alert_malformed(msg, row_num)
    790 return None

File c:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py:739, in PythonParser._alert_malformed(self, msg, row_num)
    722 """
    723 Alert a user about a malformed row, depending on value of
    724 `self.on_bad_lines` enum.
   (...)
    736     even though we 0-index internally.
    737 """
    738 if self.on_bad_lines == self.BadLineHandleMethod.ERROR:
--> 739     raise ParserError(msg)
    740 elif self.on_bad_lines == self.BadLineHandleMethod.WARN:
    741     base = f"Skipping line {row_num}: "

ParserError: ',' expected after '"'
```

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Comment: Does it work if you remove `engine='python'`

Comment: @Chris no it doesn't

Comment: When it comes to json datatables, it is common practice to set the dlimiter as the pipeline symbol. "|", that way it avoids the issue that you are having. Is worth noting, that way pandas has an easier time reading your dataframe.

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: Control panel -> Date time setting -> Number formats -> Additional settings -> list separator put the pipleline, set it as a delimiter in your  csv you should be gucci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `escapechar='\\'` solve the problem and catch all the 24 columns.

```py
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=",", engine="python", escapechar='\\')
```